# How to get Mask with transparency in pygame?

Tags: python, pygame, mask

I'm writing a game in Python with Pygame, and I'm trying to keep my player sprite from touching trees dotted around the map. My player's sprite has transparency (of course), and when I load a Pygame Mask with `pygame.mask.from_surface(self.getNextFrame())`, it only loads the parts with actual color.

My question is, does anyone know how to get pygame to load the mask WITH the transparency from the original image?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, use the second argument:

```
mask = pygame.mask.from_surface(self.getNextFrame(), 0)
```

By setting it to `0` any pixel is seen as opaque. See [the documentation](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/mask.html#pygame.mask.from_surface).

Please note that the result of this is simply a rectangle of the size of the surface. So it might actually be more performant to use this:

```
mask = pygame.mask.Mask(self.getNextFrame().get_size())
mask.fill()
```

Comment: @Cornholio: also, if my answer solved your problem do not forget to accept it by clicking the green checkbox to the left of my answer. This gives me a little bit of rep and marks the answer answered, which is great for future users as well.

Comment: Update: Worked GREAT! I used the second method and it's much better.